jest-mongodb and Typescript - Error loading preset
Seems like can't load preset
file: jest.config.js
 preset: "@shelf/jest-mongodb",

Issue Summary

The problem arises from global.__MONGO_URI__, which returns undefined.
run test command (package.json): "test": "jest --passWithNoTests",
Runs on window
Using GitBash
After successful installation, during execution, the globalConfig.json file is generated, which includes the uri and dbname.

enter image description here
Error
enter image description here
error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no 

Instalation
jest-mongodb-config.js
module.exports = {
  mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
    instance: {
      dbName: 'jest',
    },
    binary: {
      version: '4.0.3',
      skipMD5: true,
    },
    autoStart: false,
  },
};

jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src", "<rootDir>/tests"],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts',
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  preset: "@shelf/jest-mongodb",
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    ".+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@/tests/(.*)': '<rootDir>/tests/$1',
    '@/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.ts$", 
};

usage
  beforeAll(async () => {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    } as ConnectOptions)
    db = client.db()
  })

I've tried:

reinstall jest-mongodb
create a new project following the docs
reload, close and reopen vscode
using process.env.MONGO_URL
install with:

 npm --save-dev @shelf/jest-mongodb

 yarn add @shelf/jest-mongodb --dev


Solved!
I get the content from process.env and find MONGO_URL.
So I changed:
global.__MONGO_URI__

To
process.env.MONGO_URL

Do Not Use with underscores! It won't work
process.env.__MONGO_URL__

